# Caching MySQL UNION Queries

Tags: mysql, caching, union, query-cache

I've read that MySQL can cache `UNION's`, but at the same time I have read that..

> Avoid comment (and space) in the start of the query – Query Cache does
>   simple optimization to check if query can be cached. As I mentioned
>   only SELECT queries are cached – so it looks at first letter of the
>   query and if it is “S” it proceeds with query lookup in cache if not –
>   skips it.

Source: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/27/mysql-query-cache/

So with that said, since UNION's start with a parentheses how are they cached?

As per mysql.com:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
```

First letter is NOT an "S", so it would be skipped!?

I've also seen you can do something like this..

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
) AS u
```

But then it would be a `sub-select` and hence, according to that page, won't be cached either.

So how do `UNION`s get cached then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because every `SELECT` query can be written with `'S'` as it's starting letter.

you don't need to write sub-query to cache this `UNION` query as brackets can be removed from your query and can be modified as:

```
SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10
UNION
SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: That's weird. I tried it without the parentheses before and it gave me a syntax error, just tried it again and it worked. Must of been doing something wrong before haha..... thanks!

Comment: Ya I know, sometimes happens with me also. You're welcome! :)